# MySQL Triggers - 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - strange behavior not every time works

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have been developed an application on python 3 using tornado framework that connects to a huge MySQL database, millions of rows inside.

This database is synchronized in real-time, so data are inserted and deleted and updated, so was created 3 triggers insert, update and delete.

But the triggers behave very strange, sometime they work and sometime they do not work, like when they decide they pickup the data and do what they have to do, other time they just ignore it.

**MySQL version is this one 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1**

As well i inserted the 3 triggers that are in my database, maybe is a logic error in my triggers:

**INSERT**

```
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM USERS_STATS WHERE LOGIN = NEW.LOGIN) = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO USERS_STATS (LOGIN) values (NEW.LOGIN);
  END IF;
  UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
    TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT + IF(NEW.CMD = 6 AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND NEW.PROFIT > 0, NEW.PROFIT, 0),
    TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW + IF(NEW.CMD = 6 AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND NEW.PROFIT < 0, NEW.PROFIT, 0),
    TOTAL_VOLUME = TOTAL_VOLUME + IF(NEW.CMD IN(0, 1) AND NEW.CLOSE_TIME > '1970-01-01', NEW.VOLUME, 0),
    TOTAL_REBATE = TOTAL_REBATE + IF((NEW.COMMENT LIKE '%agent%' OR NEW.COMMENT LIKE '%rebate%' OR NEW.COMMENT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%'), ROUND(NEW.PROFIT, 2), 0)
  WHERE LOGIN = NEW.LOGIN;
END
```

**UPDATE**

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE old_is_deposit integer;
  DECLARE new_is_deposit integer;
  DECLARE old_is_withdraw integer;
  DECLARE new_is_withdraw integer;
  DECLARE old_is_rebate integer;
  DECLARE new_is_rebate integer;
  SET old_is_deposit := OLD.CMD = 6 AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND OLD.PROFIT > 0;
  SET new_is_deposit := NEW.CMD = 6 AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND NEW.PROFIT > 0;
  SET old_is_withdraw := OLD.CMD = 6 AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND OLD.PROFIT < 0;
  SET new_is_withdraw := NEW.CMD = 6 AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND NEW.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND NEW.PROFIT < 0;
  SET old_is_rebate := OLD.COMMENT LIKE '%agent%' OR OLD.COMMENT LIKE '%rebate%' OR OLD.COMMENT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%';
  SET new_is_rebate := NEW.COMMENT LIKE '%agent%' OR NEW.COMMENT LIKE '%rebate%' OR NEW.COMMENT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%';
  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM USERS_STATS WHERE LOGIN = NEW.LOGIN) = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO USERS_STATS (LOGIN) values (NEW.LOGIN);
  END IF;
  IF (old_is_deposit = 1 AND new_is_deposit = 1 AND OLD.PROFIT != NEW.PROFIT) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT + (NEW.PROFIT - OLD.PROFIT)
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_withdraw = 1 AND new_is_withdraw = 1 AND OLD.PROFIT != NEW.PROFIT) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW + (NEW.PROFIT - OLD.PROFIT)
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_deposit = 1 AND new_is_withdraw = 1) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT - OLD.PROFIT,
      TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW + NEW.PROFIT
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_withdraw = 1 AND new_is_deposit = 1) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT + NEW.PROFIT,
      TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW - OLD.PROFIT
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_deposit = 0 AND new_is_deposit = 1) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT + NEW.PROFIT
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_deposit = 1 AND new_is_deposit = 0) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT - OLD.PROFIT
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_withdraw = 0 AND new_is_withdraw = 1) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW + NEW.PROFIT
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_withdraw = 1 AND new_is_withdraw = 0) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW - OLD.PROFIT
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  END IF;
  IF (OLD.VOLUME != NEW.VOLUME) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_VOLUME = TOTAL_VOLUME + (NEW.VOLUME - OLD.VOLUME)
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  END IF;
  IF (old_is_rebate = 1 AND new_is_rebate = 1 AND OLD.PROFIT != NEW.PROFIT) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_REBATE = TOTAL_REBATE + (ROUND(NEW.PROFIT, 2) - ROUND(OLD.PROFIT, 2))
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_rebate = 0 AND new_is_rebate = 1) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_REBATE = TOTAL_REBATE + ROUND(NEW.PROFIT, 2)
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  ELSEIF (old_is_rebate = 1 AND new_is_rebate = 0) THEN
    UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
      TOTAL_REBATE = TOTAL_REBATE - ROUND(OLD.PROFIT, 2)
    WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
  END IF;
END
```

**DELETE**

```
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM USERS_STATS WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN) = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO USERS_STATS (LOGIN) values (OLD.LOGIN);
  END IF;
  UPDATE USERS_STATS SET
    TOTAL_DEPOSIT = TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IF(OLD.CMD = 6 AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND OLD.PROFIT > 0, OLD.PROFIT, 0),
    TOTAL_WITHDRAW = TOTAL_WITHDRAW - IF(OLD.CMD = 6 AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%internal%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%Tr %' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%rebate%' AND OLD.COMMENT NOT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%' AND OLD.PROFIT < 0, OLD.PROFIT, 0),
    TOTAL_VOLUME = TOTAL_VOLUME - IF(OLD.CMD IN(0, 1) AND OLD.CLOSE_TIME > '1970-01-01', OLD.VOLUME, 0),
    TOTAL_REBATE = TOTAL_REBATE - IF((OLD.COMMENT LIKE '%agent%' OR OLD.COMMENT LIKE '%rebate%' OR OLD.COMMENT LIKE '%MAM:CASH%'), ROUND(OLD.PROFIT, 2), 0)
  WHERE LOGIN = OLD.LOGIN;
END
```

As well i attached the screenshot how the triggers sit:
[image]

Need help why my triggers are not working properly.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Problem with Triggers is that they are very hard to debug. Anyways, most likely you are having Transaction Deadlock Issues, and triggers are failing due to "Wait time exceeded" errors (not ignoring).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya when testing manual yes they work as they have to work, but not on production, what u mean Transaction Deadlock Issues? And how can be fixed?

Comment: Triggers basically lock the tables they are working on. So, lets say you have tables A, B, C. Trigger 1 Locks from A to B to C. Trigger 2 Locks from C to B to A. Both are simultaneously trying to lock same table from either sides, hence there is a deadlock.

Comment: It is not easy to solve. You will have to rework logic of your triggers. Do read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i think this can happen, because we speak about huge amount of data and they are synchronized minimum 1001 rows at same time, so 1001 rows are coming at once in MySQL. But i guess must be some tricks on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i found a different logic, could not escape out of Deadlock in my case, so instead of above triggers with a cronjob script i was able to update all necessary data on one interval of time that triggers was doing.